# why does scan in DS2 handle backslashes different from old school SAS?

Tags: escaping, sas, sas-ds2

I use the functions to count words words `countw` and to get words `scan` a lot to analyse full file names. *(For those interested, I typically use `FILENAME docDir PIPE "dir ""&docRoot"" /B/S";`)*

With traditional SAS, this works both on UNIX and Windows:

```
data OLD_SCHOOL;
    format logic withSlash withBack secondSlash secondBack $20.;

    logic = 'OLD_SCHOOL';

    withSlash = 'Delimited/With/Slash';
    wordsSlash = countw(withSlash, '/');
    secondSlash = scan(withSlash, 2, '/');

    withBack = 'Delimited\With\Back';
    wordsBack = countw(withBack, '\');
    secondBack = scan(withBack, 2, '\');

    worksTheSame = wordsSlash eq wordsBack and secondSlash eq secondBack;

    put _all_;
run;
```

results in

```
    withSlash=Delimited/With/Slash secondSlash=With wordsSlash=3
    withBack=Delimited\With\Back   secondBack=With  wordsBack=3 
    worksTheSame=1
```

Using the newer DS2 syntax, scan and countw handle backslash differently

```
proc ds2;
data DS2_SCHOOL / overwrite=yes;
    dcl double wordsSlash wordsBack worksTheSame;
    dcl char(20)logic withSlash withBack secondSlash secondBack;
    method init();
        logic = 'DB2_SCHOOL';

        withSlash = 'Delimited/With/Slash';
        wordsSlash = countw(withSlash, '/');
        secondSlash = scan(withSlash, 2, '/');

        withBack = 'Delimited\With\Back';
        wordsBack = countw(withBack, '\');
        secondBack = scan(withBack, 2, '\');

        worksTheSame = (wordsSlash eq wordsBack) and (secondSlash eq secondBack);       
    end;
enddata;
run;
quit;

data BOTH_SCHOOLS;
    set OLD_SCHOOL DS2_SCHOOL;
run;
```

results in

```
    withSlash=Delimited/With/Slash secondSlash=With wordsSlash=3
    withBack=Delimited\With\Back   secondBack=      wordsBack=1 
    worksTheSame=0
```

Is there a good reason for this, or should I report it as a bug to SAS?

*(There might be a link with the role of backslash in regular expressions.)*

Comment: I tried creating a work around using `translate(withBack, '/', '\')`, but the translation does not happen.

Comment: It works for me with SAS 9.4. What version of SAS are you using?

Comment: I had this issue with Enterprise Guide, and I just repeated it with the traditional user interface of SAS 9.4

Comment: On the theory that somehow \ is being treated as an escape character, what happens if you double them up?

Comment: What specific release of 9.4 are you running? (I'm running TS1M3, and it works fine for me both in DM and EG 7.1.)

Comment: @Tom, ´wordsBack = countw(withBack, '\\');´ and ´secondBack = scan(withBack, 2, '\\');´ still give the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I verified this in 9.3 (which is missing overwrite=yes, as a side note, annoyingly):

```
proc ds2;
data DS2_SCHOOL ;
    dcl double wordsSlash wordsBack worksTheSame;
    dcl char(20)logic withSlash withBack secondSlash secondBack;
    method init();
        logic = 'DB2_SCHOOL';

        withSlash = 'Delimited/With/Slash';
        wordsSlash = countw(withSlash, '/');
        secondSlash = scan(withSlash, 2, '/');

        withBack = 'Delimited\\With\\Back';
        wordsBack = countw(withBack, '\\');
        secondBack = scan(withBack, 2, '\\');

        worksTheSame = (wordsSlash eq wordsBack) and (secondSlash eq secondBack);       
    end;
enddata;
run;
quit;
```

The backslash indeed seems to be an escape - even in your original string you need a pair of them.

This is no longer the case as of 9.4 TS1M3, so it's unclear where between 9.3 TS1M2 and 9.4 TS1M3 this was changed and/or fixed - and it's not mentioned in any of the change logs, unfortunately.

According to comments/verification, it looks like it was changed/fixed in 9.4 TS1M2 specifically.

Comment: I have the problem in 9.4 TS1M1, so it is fixed in 9.4 TS1M2

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Joe. To further proof you got it right: if I specify my strings in an old school data step:

```
Data FROM_OLD_SCHOOL;
    delimiter = '/';
    fullName = 'Delimited/With/Slash';
    output;

    delimiter = '\';
    fullName = 'Delimited\With\Back';
    output;
run;
```

I can perfectly use them in a DS2 data step:

```
proc ds2;
data DS2_SCHOOL / overwrite=yes;
    dcl double partsPresent;
    dcl char(20) secondPart;
    method run();
        set FROM_OLD_SCHOOL;

        partsPresent = countw(fullName, delimiter);
        secondPart = scan(fullName, 2, delimiter);
    end;
enddata;
run;
quit;
```

results in

```
Obs partsPresent secondPart delimiter fullName 
1   3            With       /         Delimited/With/Slash 
2   3            With       \         Delimited\With\Back
```